# Cache Google Search Results?

Tags: google, search

I am going to be working on a closeted windows domain consisting of 15 workstations and one DC. It has not access to the internet. I would like to bring as much with me as possible, thinking of various manuals and whatnot, but I am really interested to know if it is possible to cache the first 20 or so results of various google search queries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some "Website copier" like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). This tool is much better than manually saving pages.

You can even feed it with search result pages, and it will get all links inside this page (with configured depth).

Answer (score 0):

You could run the search and save the HTML of the results page. Simply, but effective.